# Locked out of drive on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, permissions, chmod, chown

I was trying to delete some torrents that I had downloaded with transmission-daemon and was unable to from my samba share on windows due to transmission's default file creation permissions.

I figured the best solution was to `sudo chmod -R 0777 /media/Storage` (my drive with samba) but apparently not.

This locked both my windows user and my user on my ubuntu server out of the drive completely, with a message saying `ls: cannot access /media/Storage: Permission denied`.

I am able to login as root with `sudo bash` and make changes however I am uncertain as to how to make my drive accessible again.

Doing a `ls -ld` on the directory shows `drwsrwsrwx 39 root root 4096 Nov 17 21:20 /media/Storage`.

I have also done a: `sudo chown -R [username]:[group] /media/Storage` and a `sudo chmod -R u+rw /media/Storage`.  Both commands executed without errors but had no good effect.

I am running ubuntu-server 12.10 so no GUI available.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have the SetUID and SetGID bits set, which are causing things to be owned root.root, and otherwise making you have a Bad Day.

`sudo chmod -R u-s,g-s /media/Storage` should fix you up.